# Not able to download the file if a model dialog is already opened

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> We opened an popup by using jquery extension.Our requirement is to
>   download a file on click of button present in popup. My code is like
>   this:-

```
JS code:-
showModalData: function (obj) {
        var url = OC.MVC.util.getLink("Employee", "GetDetail");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (result) {                         
                $.modal(result);//open the modal popup
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }

Controller code:-
 public virtual ActionResult GetDetail(Employee model)
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }

View:-
<div>
@Html.Raw(Html.Button("btnDownload", "Download").ToString())
<div>
```

> Now on click of Download I have to download the file for this code
>   is:-

```
  public ActionResult Download()
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\New\note.txt");
            string fileName = "note.txt";
            return (File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName));

        }
```

> On click of download button it will call the Download action defined
>   in controller.**Now return (File(fileBytes,
>   System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName)); should
>   opens the save dialog** to select the path to save the document.**But
>   it is not opening the save dialog box**.It is also not showing error
>   and nothing is happening.Note: Download button present in Modal Popup.

Comment: you'll have to give us a bit more info than "not working". What exactly happens (or doesn't happen)? Show us the results of your debugging work please. You need to narrow down the problem a bit. Is it simply that the modal popup stops you from clicking on the button, or can you click, but there's some sort of problem or error? There's nothing in your code to give it away.

Comment: @ADyson I updated the question.Let me know if it needs more clarification.

Comment: have you watched in your browser's developer tools to see if a request to the "download" action is fired, and, if so, what response you get from the server? You can also add a "click" Javascript event to see if the button is even getting clicked. Also you can set a debug breakpoint in your server code to see if the server code is executing, and you can check your server's event viewer for errors. Lots of debugging you can do. When I asked for more info, that's the sort of thing I meant. As a programmer you should carry out those kind of tasks as standard when you have an issue.

Comment: @ADyson I debugged in browser and server also, it is hitting the download method and after return statement nothing is happening, it is not showing any error also.

Comment: so what response do you get from the server? Anything? If nothing is received then eventually it should at least time out.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=note.txt
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcbmF0aGdvXFNvdXJjZVxXb3Jrc3BhY2VzXFdvcmtzcGFjZVxQcm9qZWN0IE1lbWJlciBDZW50cmVcRmVhdHVyZXNcMTguMDZCQVVcTWVtYmVyQ2VudHJlLldlYlxNZW1iZXJDZW50cmUuV2ViLkFkbWluXEZ1bmRNYW5hZ2VtZW50XFBkc1xkb3duTG9hZFJlcG9ydA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 17 May 2018 10:23:39 GMT
Content-Length: 18 @ADyson this is the reponse I am getting.

Comment: @ADyson I think already one popup is opened that why it is not able to open a save dialog.

Comment: a modal popup is just a CSS trick, it's not a real browser popup. That response looks like the file data. Is it trying to download via ajax or something, instead of a regular request?

Comment: no download method only downloading file,as it is defined above, return (File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName)); should open a file save dialog to select the path to download the file.

Comment: only if it's requested properly, and not via ajax. The type of request is determined by the setup of the button (and any associated Javascript) running in the browser, not the server. I don't know what your "download" button is configured to do - I can't even see the final HTML generated by your Razor code, and I don't know if there are Javascript events attached to it.

Comment: so it is browser issue I guess,

Comment: well maybe an issue with the code which runs in the browser, rather than an issue with the browser itself. Downloading files via ajax just doesn't work, it makes no sense because it just returns the file data into a Javascript variable, instead of actually causing a proper download to the user's disk. I haven't got enough info to prove that's what's happening but it's certainly a strong possibility.

Comment: @ADyson same Download method is working if it is called from normal page.

Comment: so...as I keep saying, you need to find out if in in this case it's called via ajax instead. There's obviously some kind of difference in what happens "normally" and what happens in this specific case. You haven't shown me enough code or given me enough info to be able to identify what the difference is, but clearly there must be one. You need to look carefully and find it. You should be able to detect using your browser's network tools whether the request to the Download action is made via AJAX (sometimes called XHR) or not - you can set a filter to only show up XHR requests, for example.

Comment: Or there might possibly be a `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` in the headers of the request if it's being done via ajax. And apart from all that, you need to look at your codebase, the relevant parts of which I cannot see. It may simply be a case of trial and error and ruling things out. Maybe you need to strip back the code until it works again, I don't know. But it's in your hands I'm afraid, all I can do is advise from the sidelines as I have been doing, unless you provide relevant detail into the question.

Comment: @ADyson It is working fine thanks for your suggestion.I removed the ajax call of the download button and called the Download method directly from button.

Comment: I thought it would probably be that. Glad you got it working. I have written that as the answer (obviously I can't provide a code example since I don't know what you removed) for future reference to anyone finding this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your download action is called via a normal HTTP request from the browser, and not via an AJAX call initiated via JavaScript.